# Stop a service after MainActivity is closed (EDITED)

Tags: android, android-service

I think im not clear at all, i do want the service to persist even if the main activity is destroyed via user action or android system does it, it does it well, but when the app is reopened at certain point i will want to check if a bg activity exists and stop it using a action button, THX in advance.

---

I launch a background service, in my `MainActivity` I can stop it and rerun it, the service persists when the app is closed from the running apps list, the problem is when I relaunch the closed app an try to stop the service with a button I have the app crashes cause it obviously tries to stop a service from which it no longer has a reference.

```
private void startBg(){

    if (!hasPermissions() || mScanning) {
        return;
    }

    clearLogs();

    BgServiceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BgScanService.class);
    startService(BgServiceIntent);
}
private void stopBg(){
    stopService(BgServiceIntent);
}
```

Calling `stopBg()` after reopening the app fails, because `BgServiceIntent` no longer points to this service and thus I get this:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: mobile.link.imbera.apsys.imberalink, PID: 20104
              java.lang.NullPointerException
                  at android.app.ContextImpl.validateServiceIntent(ContextImpl.java:1568)
                  at android.app.ContextImpl.stopServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1628)
                  at android.app.ContextImpl.stopService(ContextImpl.java:1589)
                  at android.content.ContextWrapper.stopService(ContextWrapper.java:499)
                  at mobile.link.imbera.apsys.imberalink.MainActivity.stopBg(MainActivity.java:180)
                  at mobile.link.imbera.apsys.imberalink.MainActivity.lambda$onCreate$1$MainActivity(MainActivity.java:124)
                  at mobile.link.imbera.apsys.imberalink.MainActivity$$Lambda$1.onClick(Unknown Source)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4463)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18770)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Use the MainActivity's     @ Override
    protected void onResume() and     @ Override
    protected void onPause()  to start and stop the service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the service already running in background then you need to call **stopSelf()** on same instance of that service .
Now as per service life Cycle **onCreate()** only call once in the lifetime of service .
WhereAs **onStartCommand** get called each time you call startService() with new intent. So what you can do is to pass a flag in intent to stop it .

```
Intent BgServiceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BgScanService.class);
    BgServiceIntent.putExtra("close",true);
    startService(BgServiceIntent);
```

And in Service .

```
 @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    boolean shouldClose=intent.getBooleanExtra("close",false);
    if(shouldClose){
        stopSelf();
    } else {
        // Continue to action here
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe all you need to do is check to see if it's `null` before attempting to stop it:

```
private void stopBg(){
     if(BgServiceIntent != null)
         stopService(BgServiceIntent);
}
```

Comment: I think it will alaways be null cause the mainactivity was destroyed, what i want is a way to retrieve the running instance or its startId or something to kill it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

First of all start a service in **START_NOT_STICKY**.
Override this method in your Service

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

and add this in your MainActivity.class

```
@override
private onDestroy() {
    stopService(YourActiveService);
    finishAffinity();
    super.onDestroy()
}
```

Comment: i do want it to be sticky, thats the point of being a bg service, i want it to persist even if the main app dies but i need a method to retrieve that instance when i reopened the previously clsed main activity and stopped in that point