# How to manually stop a service?

Tags: android, android-service

I have tried to stop my service, even my **destroy** method also executed but my service is not stopping. I have done my best. Please help me.

my code is mentioned below:

MainActivity

1. Intent intent=new Intent(this,Myservice.class);
      startService(intent);     //in start button.
2. Intent intent=new Intent(this,Myservice.class);
        stopService(intent);    //in stop button.

Myservice

```
public class Myservice extends Service {
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this,"runing",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     {
         myTherad th=new myTherad();
         Thread thread=new Thread(th);
         thread.start();


     }

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this,"stop",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    super.onDestroy();

}

class myTherad implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (this)
        {
            try {

                for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
                {
                    wait(1000);
                    Log.d("mfnhsdgjkfn","===="+String.valueOf(i));
                }

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        stopSelf();


    }


}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop running services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9964356/how-to-stop-running-services)

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47806235/4168607).

Comment: stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));  and handle the service stop process in OnDestroy method of service if needed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [stop service in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555765/stop-service-in-android)

Comment: Just to check-  you understand that stopping a service does NOT stop thread started by your service, right?  The code to stop services has no idea threads exist.  You have to do that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think your service is stopped, but not your `Thread`. Cancel your Thread as well in `onDestroy` of your service by introducing for e.g. some kind of state variable:

```
 class myTherad implements Runnable {
     // Indicates that the runnable should stop. 
     private boolean shouldStop = false;

     @Override
     public void run() {
        synchronized (this)
        {
            try {

                for(int i=0;i<10 && !shouldStop;i++)
                {
                    wait(1000);
                    Log.d("mfnhsdgjkfn","===="+String.valueOf(i));
                }

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        stopSelf();


  }
```

and declare your runnable as class attribute:

```
private myTherad runnable;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    runnable=new myTherad();
    Thread thread=new Thread(runnable);
    thread.start();

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

}
```

and stop the runnable within your `onDestroy`:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this,"stop",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    runnable.shouldStop = true;
    super.onDestroy();

}
```

At least after the latest `wait` was executed, your thread should stop. You can optimize that, with an interruption.

Answer (score 0):

We have to inturrpt thread that is running , `thread.interrupt()` will do that and give `java.lang.InterruptedException` , Try below code :

```
public class MyService extends Service {
public MyService() {}
myTherad th;
Thread thread;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this,"runing",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    {
         th=new myTherad();
         thread=new Thread(th);
         thread.start();
    }
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(this,"stop",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    thread.interrupt();
}

class myTherad implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (this)
        {
            try {

                for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
                {
                    wait(1000);
                    Log.d("LOG","===="+String.valueOf(i));
                }

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        stopSelf();
    }
}
}
```